# Send mails in an asynchronous process

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using `drupal_mail()` to send mails from the HTML formatted content.

It takes more time to send mails. Actually, Mail is triggered while the form submission after the save logic.

To save the page loading time, how can I send emails in an asynchronous process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a pre-built solution goes, you can try the [Background process](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process) module, which would theoretically allow you to do something like:

```
$handle = background_process_start('drupal_mail', $module, $key, $to, ...);
```

Beyond that Drupal has nothing to help, so If you don’t use that module, just approach this as a general PHP task. The options and difficulties for async/background processing in PHP are very well documented around the web.